# How to extract SMS/MMS from Android to readable format?

Tags: sms, backup

Looking for a way to extract text messages, photos included, to a readable format like HTML, PDF, RTF, etc. Is there any free software that can achieve this?

Comment: I feel easy with SMS, but not with MMS.